# Asp.net GridView RowUpdating returning old values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to make an editable `GridView`, and when `RowUpdating` is called the values I get from the `TextBoxes` are the old values and not the new ones.

My GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderWidth="1px" DataKeyNames="phoneId" 
    onrowcancelingedit="GVProducts_RowCancelingEdit" 
    onrowdeleting="GVProducts_RowDeleting" 
    onrowediting="GVProducts_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GVProducts_RowUpdating" 
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" EditText="ערוך" HeaderText="עריכה" 
            InsertText="הוסף" NewText="חדש" SelectText="בחר" ShowEditButton="True" 
            UpdateText="עדכן" CancelText="בטל" DeleteText="מחק" 
            InsertVisible="False" CausesValidation="False" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" CancelText="בטל" DeleteText="מחק" 
            EditText="ערוך" InsertText="הוסף" NewText="חדש" SelectText="בחר" 
            ShowDeleteButton="True" UpdateText="עדכן" HeaderText="מחיקה" 
            CausesValidation="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="phoneId" HeaderText="מספר מכשיר" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="phoneId" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="צבע">
            <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
            <FooterStyle Width="100px" />
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="חברה">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblBrand" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="דגם">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblModel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="כמות" SortExpression="amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("amount") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("amount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="כמות מינימלית" SortExpression="minAmount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("minAmount") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("minAmount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="מחיר" SortExpression="price" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="תמונה">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"pic","images/{0}") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
</asp:GridView>
```

My RowEditing (UpdateGVLabel is not related):

```
protected void GVProducts_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GVProducts.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GVProducts.DataSource = products;

    UpdateGVlabel();
    //products = connection.GetData("Select * From Products", "Products");
    if (products.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ((TextBox)GVProducts.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[6].Controls[1]).Text = products.Rows[e.NewEditIndex][4].ToString();
        ((TextBox)GVProducts.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[7].Controls[1]).Text = products.Rows[e.NewEditIndex][5].ToString();
    }
}
```

My RowUpdating (UpdateGVLabel is not related):

```
protected void GVProducts_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    bool abort = false;
    int amount = 0, minAmount = 0;
    int id = int.Parse(GVProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text);
    try
    {
        amount = int.Parse(((TextBox)GVProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[1]).Text);
        minAmount = int.Parse(((TextBox)GVProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Controls[1]).Text);
        if (amount < minAmount)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("אין אפשרות להגדיר כמות שקטנה מהכמות המינימלית!");
            abort = true;
        }
        if (minAmount <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("כמות מינימלית לא יכולה להיות אפס או פחות!\nאם ברצונך לציין שהחנות לא מוכרת את המכשיר הזה, יש ללחוץ על \"מחק\"");
            abort = true;
        }
        if (amount < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("כמות לא יכולה להיות שלילית");
            abort = true;
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("כמויות חייבות להיות מספרים!");
        abort = true;
    }
    if (!abort)
    {
        connection = new Connect(Server.MapPath("App_Data/ado1.mdb"));
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Update Products Set amount=" + amount + ", minAmount=" + minAmount + " Where phoneId=" + id;
        products = connection.GetData("Select * From Products", "Products");
        connection.ChangeDatabase(cmd); GVProducts.EditIndex = -1;
        GVProducts.DataSource = products;

        UpdateGVlabel();

        MessageBox.Show("המכשיר נערך בהצלחה!");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is  UpdateGVlabel();
in your Code ?

Comment: I have fields which should be displayed with background and such, so this method does this. It does not related to my problem

Comment: what have you written in page load?have you bind the gridview in page load?did you check isPostback?

Comment: No. But when I add an if statement with DataBind(), it doesn't show the `GridView` at all

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
protected void GVProducts_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
//your code

 if (!abort)
    {
        connection = new Connect(Server.MapPath("App_Data/ado1.mdb"));
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Update Products Set amount=" + amount + ", minAmount=" + minAmount + " Where phoneId=" + id;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//OR "connection.ChangeDatabase(cmd);" if it updates your database
        products = connection.GetData("Select * From Products", "Products");
        GVProducts.EditIndex = -1;
        GVProducts.DataSource = products;
        GVProducts.DataBind();
        UpdateGVlabel();

        MessageBox.Show("המכשיר נערך בהצלחה!");
    }
}
```

The problem was you were calling `connection.ChangeDatabase(cmd);` to update your database after fetching data from table like this `products = connection.GetData("Select * From Products", "Products");` hence you always got old values from your db and values in your db also got updated too..

Also add this `GVProducts.DataBind();` after providing datasource `GVProducts.DataSource = products;` to bind the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Write The code in the row updating

```
 int i=convert.toint32(e.NewValues["Standard"])
```

Answer (score 0):

IsPostBack() is the answer. We have to check if the Page is posted back or not. If not, then we will bind the Grid.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Reference : https://taditdash.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/why-gridview-rowupdating-event-is-not-giving-the-updated-values/